# How to append OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS in xcconfig

Tags: gdataxml, xcconfig

I am using GDataXML, which requires

```
// libxml includes require that the target Header Search Paths contain
//
//   /usr/include/libxml2
//
// and Other Linker Flags contain
//
//   -lxml2
```

In my xconfig, I have done the first part with

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=/usr/include/libxml2 $(HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS)
```

But I just cannot make the second part, like

```
OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS=-libxml2
```

,which I have tried out several conbimation with $(inherit), etc. So that `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` keeps coming out.

Any thoughts on that? Thanks!